# Unable to install ubuntu 20.04 on HP DL380, DL360 Gen8

Tags: boot, 20.04, hp, flash

I downloaded 20.04 ISO from Ubuntu.com and created a bootable USB using Rufus tool. The target servers were used HP DL380, DL360 Gen8. I could not succeed to install the Ubuntu on any of the servers. I am reaching the Ubuntu installation menu but once i finish the menu details the installation fails. Is it a compatibility issue or the USB bootable software problem or what am I missing. By the way, the installation of windows 10 as a trial went successful on one of the above machines. Any help.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same a few days back and failed too. Turns out it was a USB 3.0 compatibility issue with me, then I tried using the 2.0 slot and it worked. Don't know if there's a reason behind this or was it just with me.

Comment: Thank you bro I will try that and feedback.

Comment: I am new in this area can you please explain more for me. What was exactly changed and made it work. Have you changed the USB to 2.0 instead of USB 3.0 .

Comment: I used the USB 2.0 port while making the bootable disk image. (didn't changed the USB drive, though you can try that too in case above workaround doesn't work). And to be honest, I couldn't find any legit reason behind the same, but I did read some articles mentioning it. So it is possible that this may or may not work in your case. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you dude I have succeeded in installing the 20.04 on DL360 Gen8.

Comment: I replaced the previous server (DL360)  with another one of the same specs and plugged the 3.0 USB drive into the second USB port from top on the back of the new one DL360 server. I am not sure if the previous hardware was having a e defect or not but the new approach made things ok. Thank you again bro.

Comment: Have a great experience on your server!!